# What does しといてくれて mean here?

Tags: meaning, sentence

I have come across this line in a book:

> それは秘密にしといてくれてもよかったんだぜ…？

However I am unsure what しといてくれて is supposed to mean and what the above would therefore translate to, I've tried looking online but I couldn't find an explanation.

I have read about くれて and I understand that carries the meaning of having something done for you/to give etc. but I have to understand しといて as well to apply that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

それは秘密にしといてくれてもよかったんだぜ…？

1) 私は、『あなたが、それを秘密にしておく』、あるいは『あなたが、告白する』いずれでもよかった。
I didn't care whether you kept hidden about it or confessed it.

2) あなたは、告白した。
You confessed it.

3) 私は、『あなたが、それを秘密にしておく』でもよかった。
I could accept to have you keep hidden about it.

"（あなたが）秘密にしといてくれてもよかった"
= "秘密にしといてくれる + でもよかった"
= "秘密にしておいてくれる + でもよかった"
= "秘密にして + おいてくれる + でもよかった"
= "秘密にする + おいてくれる + でもよかった"
= "秘密にする(have it hidden) + おいて(leave the situation as is) + くれる((you) can) + でもよかった(I could accept that...)"

---

"それは秘密にしといてくれてもよかったんだぜ" without "？" is rather normal expression. I guess this "？" suggests that "You didn't realize my intention?"